# How to fix Android Studio auto update disaster

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu

I'm developing  an android app on AS 3.3.1 on ubuntu linux for some time and every thing was fine.
Today I opened AS as usual to find out that it updated it self to 3.4 without asking and I don't know when this took place and how and it  spitting error messages about android sdk then after fixing that my code is full of errors and my themes and settings are lost.

1-How and why did this happen?
2-How to fix it and roll back?
3-How to prevent it from happening again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was something called snap installed in Ubuntu
so I used the following command in terminal emulator:

```
snap revert android-studio
```

If you are not root use:

```
sudo snap revert android-studio
```

and everything is fine.